# Resident card for EAA family member

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I have applied  for EU member resident card for the past 2 months and I haven't heard from the Home Office. Please can i know why? I am totally confused.

Comment: Two months does not sound particularly surprising to me.  Perhaps someone who has made a similar application can say how long theirs took.

Comment: The Home Office is completely swamped at the moment because of Brexit. Did they give you an estimate for the length of time it would take when you applied?